# PI watchdog logs

Tags: pi-4, watchdog

I want to start using watchdog to check if I have problem in the connection.

so I have check for ETH0 ping 10.0.0.1 (my router IP)

I have install the basic "Watchdog" from here:

```
sudo apt-get install watchdog
```

this is what I have done :(all other lines are comments , this is the only things I have change)

```
sudo nano /etc/watchdog.conf

ping                    = 10.0.0.1
interface               = eth0
retry-timeout           = 300
interval                = 30
```

as I understadn
it will ping 10.0.0.1 once every 30 seconds
and after 300 seconds of error (meaning 5 times he run the check and get no ping answer)
he will reboot

1. is my understanding correct?
2. do I need to change\add something else?
3. where can I see the log of the watchdog? and is it writing only when he is going to reboot? (when the check is OK - he willl not write anything ?)

Thanks ,

Comment: There are several items (some software & some hardware) that have been called `watchdog` over the past several years. Please tell us how you installed this watchdog on your RPi, and where (the website/URL) you these configuration settings in your question.

Comment: update the question